# OSMNX remove buildings from graph

Tags: osmnx

I am creating a graph from an osm file using graph_from_file() (it contains both the roads and buildings) using osmnx and then plotting it. While doing this, it is also plotting buildings along with the roads. Is there a way to remove buildings from this graph/just ignore buildings while creating a graph from that osm file?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you provided a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

Set the parameter retain_all to False. This includes the buildings which are usually disconnected (in my experience). You can observe the differences between the following 2 figures.

```py
G = ox.graph_from_file('try.xml', retain_all=True)
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)

[![Figure_1][1]][1]

G = ox.graph_from_file('try.xml', retain_all=False)
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)

[![Figure_2][1]][1]
￼
```

Note that I only queried highway = pedestrian and building = university using Overpass Turbo ([overpass_code](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/KoF)) which produced my .xml file.